# Does a fake data generator exists in Java?

Tags: java, data-generation

I would like to know if a **fake data generator** exists for Java. In Perl exists `Data::Faker` and there's a port to Ruby called [`faker`](http://faker.rubyforge.org/), for JavaScript `faker.js`. Someone know about a **fake data generator** for Java, that can provide random names, phone number, P.O. box number, etc...

Comment: I've never seen something like this (in the libraries java is shipping with). Maybe there is a 3rd party library that does that for you in Java. In this case you should use a search engine to find out :)

Comment: Checkout [ThinkUI](http://www.thinkui.com/datagen/index.html)

Comment: I've recently authored a library that can pass as faker-like: https://github.com/nomemory/mockneat

Comment: You could try [Datafaker](https://www.datafaker.net), a JVM library to generate fake data. It's an up to date version (Disclaimer: maintained by me).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Hibernate, try [HibernateMock](http://java-source.net/open-source/testing-tools/hibernatemock).

Also:

- [ThinkUI](http://www.thinkui.com/datagen/index.html)
- [Benerator](http://blog.jteam.nl/2009/09/10/feed-your-database/)

Comment: HibernateMock is no more:-(
But has been reborn as http://code.google.com/p/jpamock/

Comment: i tried Benerator.. it seems to be a good project ... but there is little or no gratis support on it.. activiy on this project is very low

Answer (score 51):

Try [jFairy](https://github.com/Devskiller/jfairy). This is new project in early stage.

```
Fairy fairy = Fairy.create();
Person person = fairy.person();

System.out.println(person.fullName());            // Chloe Barker
System.out.println(person.email());               // barker@yahoo.com
System.out.println(person.telephoneNumber());     // 690-950-802

Company company = fairy.company();
System.out.println(company.name());          // Robuten Associates
System.out.println(company.url());           // http://www.robuteniaassociates.com

Person salesman = fairy.person(withCompany(company));
System.out.println(salesman.fullName());     // Juan Camacho
System.out.println(salesman.companyEmail()); // juan.camacho@robuteniaassociates.com
```

PS. I'm a contributor.

Comment: We are working on adding more functionalities right now and a new version will be released soon.

Comment: How can i become a contributor too? im using it but it doesnt fit with my real life project. To be clear, it's language based, not locale based (lets say Kanada with french), or whatever you want. Language based is not fitting to a real life project. A phoneNumber is not based on language but on locale. I like the base concept and think its the best open thing by now, but its not fitting with the reality in a big project. By now i just modify the objects per reflection to fit, but i think i can provide something which is more usable. On  githu i can not see how i can contribute.

Comment: Any help is always welcome. To contribute use Pull Requests, more to read: https://guides.github.com/activities/contributing-to-open-source/

Comment: How to create test data which can start with word of my choice like "Test Chloe Barker"

Answer (score 16):

http://www.andygibson.net/blog/article/generate-test-data-with-datafactory/
How to use:

1. Add it in your `pom.xml`

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.fluttercode.datafactory</groupId>
       <artifactId>datafactory</artifactId>
       <version>0.8</version>
       <type>jar</type>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Test it...

   ```
   public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       DataFactory df = new DataFactory();
       for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {          
           String name = df.getFirstName() + " "+ df.getLastName();
           System.out.println(name);
       }
     }
    }
   ```

Output :

```
Lindsey Craft
Erica Larsen
Ryan Levine
Erika Smith
Brooklyn Sloan
Karen Mayer
Eddie O'neill
Nancy Stevens
```

Comment: It would be better if you can improve your answer.

Comment: Also check this: https://dzone.com/articles/generate-test-data-datafactory

Comment: Just what I needed, it appears to work fine.

Answer (score 15):

There is a Java port of the Perl Data::Faker - [java-faker](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker)

Comment: It's worth to use, indeed. In my opinion it's got a good l10n support.

Comment: I recently used `java-faker`, and creating an instance of `Faker` thrown a NPE. I proceeded to report an issue for this: http://github.com/DiUS/java-faker/issues/6

Comment: Most of built in faker-s are useless. Because there are  plenty of them (pokemon, startrek etc) its hard to find useful one.