# Is there any fake data generator that works with Android?

Tags: android, testing

What I'm looking for is some library like `Perl's Data::Faker, Ruby's factory_girl`. Something that allows me to generate random `Strings`, `Dates`, ... for testing.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362683/does-a-fake-data-generator-exists-in-java) other question. But I want something that has been used by someone with Android.

Answer (score 5):

I tried java-faker, jFairy - they don't work on android.
So I find fluttercode.datafactory - it's ok for android.
Add following to your app build.gradle to use it:

```
compile 'org.fluttercode.datafactory:datafactory:0.8'
```

Usage example: http://java.dzone.com/articles/generate-test-data-datafactory

Answer (score 0):

From the link that you gave, it seems that you are looking for Mock libraries that could be used in Android.

This [article](https://sites.google.com/site/androiddevtesting/), written by some Google engineers, use [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) library to do their unit tests in Android. You might want to try it out and follow the steps in the article to have your test up and running.

Comment: Not exactly. What I need right now is something that generates basic data. For example, I want to test the creation of several Person objects and I want something that generates random names instead of hardcoding the strings.

Comment: Wow, totally different with what the link had then. =/ Well, since Perl's Faker is open-sourced, and it only create random permutation of the hardcoded data, why don't you lift the data from its source (e.g.: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/WSHELDAHL/Data-Faker-0.08/lib/Data/Faker/Name.pm) and create your own faker library. Might be even quicker than searching for appropriate libraries in the Internet.

Comment: @TanausúGonzález: This question/answers may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362683/does-a-fake-data-generator-exists-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I've recently developed a library that can be used for generating test data for your applications in a programatic way.

Take a look at MockNeat: https://github.com/nomemory/mockneat

There are also two detailed examples on the wiki page:

1. [Creating CSV with test data](https://github.com/nomemory/mockneat/wiki/Creating-CSV-files-with-arbitrary-data)
2. [Populating a SQL Schema with test data](https://github.com/nomemory/mockneat/wiki/Programatically-populate-MySQL-Schema-with-arbitrary-test-data)